# Hexdump (specifically xxd) output for exec files

Tags: hexdump

When I run a Hexdump using the command `xxd -b "textile.txt"`in OS X, the terminal prints both the binary, and the actual ASCII equivalent in the right-most column, showing the text files contents in english.

If I create a simple C program which does little else then print 'hello world' to the terminal, and i save it as a `.exec` file, the `xxd -b` command output contains binary which, when translated, is nowhere to be found in the .exec files original pre-compile source code.

Example:

```
0002034: 00000101 00000000 00000010 01011111 01101101 01101000  ..._mh
000203a: 01011111 01100101 01111000 01100101 01100011 01110101  _execu
0002040: 01110100 01100101 01011111 01101000 01100101 01100001  te_hea
0002046: 01100100 01100101 01110010 00000000 00100001 01101101  der.!m
000204c: 01100001 01101001 01101110 00000000 00100101 00000010  ain.%.
```

I am assuming that the compiling process is responsible for this, which leads me to theorise that this output in the right-most column may in fact be Assembly code.

My Question in Summary:
**What is the nature of the hex dump output for .exec files, specifically: is it assembly code, and if not, then what is it?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not really assembly; but I know it's pretty common to mix assembly and machine code.
Assembly is still a language readable by (some) humans and it must be compiled to be edible by machines. What you see here is the machine code.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code